# REGEXP_REPLACE capturing groups

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, regexp-replace

I was wondering if someone could help me understand how to use Hive's regexp_replace function to capture groups in the regex and use those groups in the replacement string.

I have an example problem I'm working through below that involves date-munging.  In this example, my goal is to take a string date that is not compatible with SimpleDateFormat parsing and make a small adjustment to get it to be compatible.  The date string (shown below) needs "GMT" prepended to the offset sign (+/-) in the string.

So, Given input:

```
  '2015-01-01 02:03:04 +0:00' 
  -or-
  '2015-01-01 02:03:04 -1:00'
```

I want output:

```
  '2015-01-01 02:03:04 GMT+0:00'
  -or-
  '2015-01-01 02:03:04 GMT-1:00'
```

Here is a simple example of a statement that I 'thought' would work, but I get strange output.

Hive query:

```
select regexp_replace('2015-01-01 02:03:04 +0:00', ' ([+-])', ' GMT\1');
```

Actual result:

```
2015-01-01 02:03:04 GMT10:00
```

Note that the "\1" should output the matched group, but instead replaces the matched group with the number "1".

Can someone help me understand the right way to reference/output matched groups in the replacement string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hive's supported notation (at least for 0.14, and I think I recall it being this way for 0.13.x as well) for regex backreferences seems to be `$1` for capture group 1, `$2` for capture group 2, etc.  It looks like it is based upon (and may even be implemented by) the [replaceAll method from the Matcher class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29).  This is the germane portion of that documentation:

> Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, and backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string.

So I think what you want is this:

```
select regexp_replace('2015-01-01 02:03:04 +0:00', ' ([+-])', ' GMT$1');
```

For example:

```
hive> select regexp_replace('2015-01-01 02:03:04 +0:00', ' ([+-])', ' GMT$1');
OK
2015-01-01 02:03:04 GMT+0:00
Time taken: 0.072 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s) 
hive> select regexp_replace('2015-01-01 02:03:04 -1:00', ' ([+-])', ' GMT$1');
OK
2015-01-01 02:03:04 GMT-1:00
Time taken: 0.144 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nither '\1' nor '$1' worked for me while trying to back-reference the captured groups in REGEXP_REPLACE.
However this worked:
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-regular-expressions/group-ref-in-replacement.html

An example: (replace hash with hyphen)

```
hive> select REGEXP_REPLACE('foo#bar','(?<tag1>foo)#(?<tag2>bar)', '${tag1}-${tag2}');
OK
foo-bar
Time taken: 0.085 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

Hope this is helpful.
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex with capturing group is working in my AWS Athena SQL query (thanks @rchang) :

```
SELECT
  regexp_replace('toto-prod-titi-prod-tata', '-prod-(.*?)-prod-', '-uat-$1-uatr-')
```

gives me as expected :

> toto-uat-titi-uatr-tata