# In PySpark, how do you properly split strings based on multiple delimiters?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to find count of words in PySpark. I am trying to split the words from the input with a list of delimiters. Here is the code that I have.

```
while(i < 18):
        splitted_words = splitted_words.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(delimiters[i]))
        i += 1
```

I am attempting to iterate through all of the delimiters and split the words using each of them in the loop. Whenever I print out the output, the delimiters are still there such as "_" or "(". Is there a better way of doing this.

Comment: Here you have your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090003/split-string-in-a-spark-dataframe-column-by-regular-expressions-capturing-groups